# how to use Log service of android while logging application events?

Tags: android, logging

I have an android application.I am logging various application **events** that occurs in the application like **login,logout** etc.I have used **log service** has core library.I have written code to **log login events** as **loginlog** which log the **number of logins,number of failed attempts** etc.Now how and where i need to **invoke this loginlog** so that the parameters/events that occurs during login is logged.

So please do give some suggestions...

**Thank you in Advance**

Comment: Give your `log` a unique `tag`. And search for it in `logcat`, so logcat will display only logs of your `tag`. For example `Log.d("YourTag", "YourMessageHere");` now search for `YourTag` in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google Analytics for that its the best tool to check real-time user opened screen and events like button click, exception and all your requirements real-time.

Please check the demo by this  [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/)

> MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
        AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
        AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
        return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    /***
     * Tracking screen view
     *
     * @param screenName screen name to be displayed on GA dashboard
     */
    public void trackScreenView(String screenName) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Set screen name.
        t.setScreenName(screenName);

        // Send a screen view.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();
    }

    /***
     * Tracking exception
     *
     * @param e exception to be tracked
     */
    public void trackException(Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

            t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                            .setDescription(
                                    new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                            .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                            .setFatal(false)
                            .build()
            );
        }
    }

    /***
     * Tracking event
     *
     * @param category event category
     * @param action   action of the event
     * @param label    label
     */
    public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Build and send an Event.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
    }

}
```

> AnalyticsTrackers .java

```
public final class AnalyticsTrackers {

    public enum Target {
        APP,
        // Add more trackers here if you need, and update the code in #get(Target) below
    }

    private static AnalyticsTrackers sInstance;

    public static synchronized void initialize(Context context) {
        if (sInstance != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Extra call to initialize analytics trackers");
        }

        sInstance = new AnalyticsTrackers(context);
    }

    public static synchronized AnalyticsTrackers getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Call initialize() before getInstance()");
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private final Map<Target, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<Target, Tracker>();
    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * Don't instantiate directly - use {@link #getInstance()} instead.
     */
    private AnalyticsTrackers(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker get(Target target) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(target)) {
            Tracker tracker;
            switch (target) {
                case APP:
                    tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled analytics target " + target);
            }
            mTrackers.put(target, tracker);
        }

        return mTrackers.get(target);
    }
}
```

and finally wherever you want to track the event just place this code

```
MyApplication.getInstance().trackEvent("Book", "Download", "Send event example");
```

> gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
```

> apptracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- End current session if app sleeps for a period of time -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!--  The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-111800416-1</string>

    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>


    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <screenName name="pacckagename.MainActivity">Home Screen</screenName>

    <screenName name="pacckagename.SecondActivity">Second Screen</screenName>

    <!--
      See Project Structure -> Analytics -> Google Analytics -> Learn More
      to learn more about configuring this file.
    -->
</resources>
```

You can track live event like this.
[image]

Comment: by using google analytics can we get raw data in xml or Json format?